# How to allow only one active useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I need to create a order logic.
I have a array of contacts and i need to ordem them.
So i create a modal with 4 options and 4 useStates, i want to create a condition like:

```
  contactsArr.sort(function (a, b) {
        if(isRecent === true){
          return (a.lastMessage.sentAt > b.lastMessage.sentAt) ? -1 : ((a.lastMessage.sentAt < b.lastMessage.sentAt) ? 1 : 0);
        }
        
        if(isOld === true){
          return (b.lastMessage.sentAt > a.lastMessage.sentAt) ? -1 : ((b.lastMessage.sentAt < a.lastMessage.sentAt) ? 1 : 0);
        }
    ...
}
```

my orderModal component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { Container, Overlay, Column, Row, Text, Button, Wrapper, Icon } from './styles';

const ModalOrder = ({modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen}) => {
  
  //change states names
  const [isSelected1, setIsSelected1] = useState(false);
  const [isSelected2, setIsSelected2] = useState(false);
  const [isSelected3, setIsSelected3] = useState(false);
  const [isSelected4, setIsSelected4] = useState(false);
  const [isSelected5, setIsSelected5] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>  
    <Overlay display={modalIsOpen ? "flex" : "none"} onClick={() => setModalIsOpen(s => !s)} >
    </Overlay>
      <Wrapper height={modalIsOpen} shadow="0px -4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);" display={"flex"} margin="10px 0 0 0" align="center" justify="center" zIndex="2011">
        {/* <Row transform={modalIsOpen ? "translateY(0)" : "translateY(327px)"} cursor="pointer" onClick={() => setModalIsOpen(s => !s)} custom="bottom: 0; position: absolute; margin-bottom: 320px; transition: all ease 0.3s;" width="90px" height="6px" background="#FFF9F9" radius="100px" shadow="0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);"></Row> */}
        <Icon custom="bottom: 0; position: absolute; margin-bottom: 310px; transition: all ease 0.3s;" transform={modalIsOpen ? "translateY(0)" : "translateY(360px)!important"} onClick={() => setModalIsOpen(s => !s)}/>
        <Column transform={modalIsOpen ? "translateY(0)" : "translateY(309px)"} align="center"  custom="bottom: 0; position: absolute; border-top-left-radius: 35px; border-top-right-radius: 35px; transition: all ease 0.3s;" width="100%" height="308px" background="#FFF" position="absolute">
          <Text margin="16px 0 12px 0" font="bold 16px/21px Segoe UI Regular" color="#448757" >Order</Text>
          
          <Button borderT="1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196, 0.8)" borderB="1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196, 0.8)" onClick={() => setIsSelected1(s => !s)} height="32px" width="100%" align="center" justify="start"> 
            <Row shadow="2px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);" display={isSelected1 ? "flex" : "none"}  custom="border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; position: absolute; left: 0;" width="10px" height="32px" background="#448757" /> 
            <Text margin="0 0 0 20px" font="normal 14px/19px Segoe UI Regular" color="#525252" >Leatest</Text> 
          </Button>
         
          <Button borderB="1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196, 0.8)" onClick={() => setIsSelected2(s => !s)} height="32px" width="100%" align="center" justify="start">
            <Row shadow="2px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);" display={isSelected2 ? "flex" : "none"}  custom="border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; position: absolute; left: 0;" width="10px" height="32px" background="#448757" />  
            <Text margin="0 0 0 20px" font="normal 14px/19px Segoe UI Regular" color="#525252" >Oldest</Text> 
          </Button>
         
          <Button borderB="1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196, 0.8)" onClick={() => setIsSelected3(s => !s)} height="32px" width="100%" align="center" justify="start">
            <Row shadow="2px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);" display={isSelected3 ? "flex" : "none"}  custom="border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; position: absolute; left: 0;" width="10px" height="32px" background="#448757" />  
            <Text margin="0 0 0 20px" font="normal 14px/19px Segoe UI Regular" color="#525252" >Read</Text> 
          </Button>
          
          <Button borderB="1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196, 0.8)" onClick={() => setIsSelected4(s => !s)} height="32px" width="100%" align="center" justify="start"> 
            <Row shadow="2px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);" display={isSelected4 ? "flex" : "none"}  custom="border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; position: absolute; left: 0;" width="10px" height="32px" background="#448757" /> 
            <Text margin="0 0 0 20px" font="normal 14px/19px Segoe UI Regular" color="#525252" >Unread</Text> 
          </Button>
 
        </Column>
      </Wrapper>
    </>
  );
};

export default ModalOrder;
```

What can i do to keep only one useState as true? (active)
Without having to create 4 different consts that set the chosen one to TRUE and the others to False

My UI

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a CustomButton component first to keep dry your code:

```
const CustomButton = ({selected, setSelected, children}) => (     
  <Button borderT="1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196, 0.8)" borderB="1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196, 0.8)" onClick={setSelected} height="32px" width="100%" align="center" justify="start"> 
    <Row shadow="2px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);" display={selected ? "flex" : "none"}  custom="border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; position: absolute; left: 0;" width="10px" height="32px" background="#448757" /> 
    <Text margin="0 0 0 20px" font="normal 14px/19px Segoe UI Regular" color="#525252" >{children}</Text> 
  </Button>
)
```

then create a state that has initial value null. Create a `buttons` variable, with its content. For this example you can use the content to set your `selected` state and compare (since all are unique), but often is better to have an unique key to it.

Then you loop through your `buttons` where you pass `selected` and `setSelected` like below:

```
const ModalOrder = ({modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen}) => {
  
  //change states names
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);
  const buttons = ['Leatest', 'Oldest', 'Read', 'Unread'];

  return (
    <>  
    <Overlay display={modalIsOpen ? "flex" : "none"} onClick={() => setModalIsOpen(s => !s)} >
    </Overlay>
      <Wrapper height={modalIsOpen} shadow="0px -4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);" display={"flex"} margin="10px 0 0 0" align="center" justify="center" zIndex="2011">
        {/* <Row transform={modalIsOpen ? "translateY(0)" : "translateY(327px)"} cursor="pointer" onClick={() => setModalIsOpen(s => !s)} custom="bottom: 0; position: absolute; margin-bottom: 320px; transition: all ease 0.3s;" width="90px" height="6px" background="#FFF9F9" radius="100px" shadow="0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);"></Row> */}
        <Icon custom="bottom: 0; position: absolute; margin-bottom: 310px; transition: all ease 0.3s;" transform={modalIsOpen ? "translateY(0)" : "translateY(360px)!important"} onClick={() => setModalIsOpen(s => !s)}/>
        <Column transform={modalIsOpen ? "translateY(0)" : "translateY(309px)"} align="center"  custom="bottom: 0; position: absolute; border-top-left-radius: 35px; border-top-right-radius: 35px; transition: all ease 0.3s;" width="100%" height="308px" background="#FFF" position="absolute">
          <Text margin="16px 0 12px 0" font="bold 16px/21px Segoe UI Regular" color="#448757" >Order</Text>
          
          { 
            buttons.map(content => (
              <CustomButton key={content} 
                      selected={selected === content}
                      setSelected={() => setSelected(content)}>{content}
              </CustomButton>
            ))
          }
 
        </Column>
      </Wrapper>
    </>
  );
};

export default ModalOrder;
```

Comment: fwiw a simple example (without the fluffy content) here https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-one-active-at-time?file=src/App.js

Comment: Worked very well, but there is a way that i can export that content ?
I need to deal with the IF

Comment: Need to do if( options === "latest"){ return ... } in another page.

Comment: that's actually another question, that depends on your how you built your app to find what 's best for you. you can move up state to a common parent `const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);` and pass down as props (that's called lift up state) to children components. You can also use the Context API to avoid prop drilling, this way you can access directly at your components.

Comment: lift up state: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html | context API: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: There is redux in the app, but I was avoiding using it, I don't have much experience with Redux, and who is dealing with redux is other guy.

Comment: redux is for more complex state management, which it doesn't seem the case. at first you can do as I say, more state upwards. if there are to many component layers that you have to pass down your props `selected` and `setSelected`, than consider using Context API

Comment: i edited https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-one-active-at-time?file=src/App.js where I lift up state to App to give you an example

Comment: This application will not work, but it is just to explain what I am doing. I'm using a constant called orderContacts that deals with filters, types of contacts and ordering. I need that every time the sort button is executed it changes the sort.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know if I'm managing to explain, it's that the project is quite big. This orderContact is in another file, I'm calling the ModalOrder component like this:
   **<ModalOrder orderContacts={orderContacts} modalIsOpen={modalIsOpenOrder} setModalIsOpen={setModalIsOpenOrder} />**

Comment: I would suggest that you consider Context API for that. you have good articles on the web on how to apply, and some SO questions about it. if even after that it seems doesn't solve it you can create another question with this specific issue. I don't want to sound unkind but your question looks answered, and you should consider to choose which answer you think that fits your need and mark it as the right one. If others questions arise it's better to create another question with its scope defined than chaining a lot of follow up question where you lose its original purpose.

Comment: yeah, i already did this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65926633/can-i-move-a-map-prop-to-another-component-file
thanks bro, i just need to see what i will do now

Answer (score 1):

Use just one state variable instead.

```
const [indexSelected, setIndexSelected] = useState(-1);
```

```
<Button onClick={() => setIndexSelected(indexSelected === 1 ? -1 : 1)} borderT="1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196, 0.8)" borderB="1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196, 0.8)" height="32px" width="100%" align="center" justify="start"> 
  <Row display={indexSelected === 1 ? "flex" : "none"} shadow="2px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);"  custom="border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; position: absolute; left: 0;" width="10px" height="32px" background="#448757" />
```

Follow the same pattern for the rest of the buttons too.

Comment: Can i do this if  **useState({type: false, order: false})** ??

Comment: Is the purpose to indicate what's being used with a property name instead of an index? If that's the case, you could use a string in state instead, like `setNameSelected(nameSelected === 'type' ? '' : 'type')`

Comment: Yes, because I have to identify each button to do the IF later. Because it will set that option on onClick, making useState change the type / order and somehow change the flex / none display of the green visual bar.

Comment: the green var appears on the left side of option

Comment: If you use the index method in the answer, you can identify the button by checking the number of `indexSelected`. For the first button you have `indexSelected === 1 ? "flex" : "none"`. For the second button you have `indexSelected === 2 ? "flex" : "none"`, and so on.

Comment: Or you can use the string method, using the same sort of comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should consider using useReducer Hook

react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer